# Javascript - save data from google trends url into PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Hi search on the web but I don't find a solution.

I would save the data from this URL http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=asdf,qwerty&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3 into a PHP array.

For now I have this code,

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=asdf,qwerty&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3';

$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$responsedata = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

echo $responsedata;


?>
```

but seems not to work.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site. I would recommend checking this out - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - for information on how to post a good question to StackOverflow. As written, your post is probably off-topic. What does your current PHP/javascript code look like?

Comment: Hi! This is my first answer in this site and i don't have experience. For now I have only separate pieces of code...

Answer (score 0):

Its JSON

```
remove // Data table response
google.visualization.Query.setResponse
```

and `);`

Then http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer! 
I have this code:

<?php
$c = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=asdf,qwerty&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3');

print($c);

?>

But the page return Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=asdf,qwerty&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 203 Non-Authoritative Information in /home4/jonathan/public_html/dev/g-trends/index-2.php on line 3. Maybe you can help me?

Comment: disable autorization or use curl

Comment: can you write the whole code please. $url = 'http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=asdf,qwerty&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3';

$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$responsedata = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);


$responsedata=str_replace("// Data table response","",$responsedata);
$responsedata=str_replace("google.visualization.Query.setResponse","",$responsedata);
$responsedata=str_replace(");","",$responsedata);

echo $responsedata;



print_r(json_decode($responsedata,true));